# PackageDescr incompatibility - Drools migration from 5.5.0 to 6.2.0

Tags: drools, jbpm, redhat-bpm

We are migrating Drools from 5.5.0 to 6.2.0. I am not able to figure compatible usage of `org.drools.compiler.lang.descr.PackageDescr` which is implementing `org.kie.internal.definition.KnowledgeDescr`. We get an instance of `PackageDescr` from `DrlParser.parse` and then creating a `org.drools.io.Resource` using `org.drools.io.ResourceFactory.newDescrResource(KnowledgeDescr)` and argument here is of type `org.drools.definition.KnowledgeDescr` which is not the same `KnowledgeDescr` that `PackageDescr` implemented above. We are not switching to KIE API as of now but using Knowledge Legacy Adapter only. What is the replacement for this issue to be fixed?

Usage example:

```
import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilder;
import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderConfiguration;
import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory;
import org.drools.builder.ResourceType;
import org.drools.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.drools.compiler.lang.descr.PackageDescr;

KnowledgeBuilderConfiguration builderConf = ...
PackageDescr pkg = ...
KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(builderConf);
// Compilation error in this line
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newDescrResource(pkg), ResourceType.DESCR);
```

Comment: Please show an example of how you're using this.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Added the usage example